# Pass param packed args into a std::queue to call with a different function later

Tags: c++, templates, queue, parameter-passing, pack-expansion

I asked a similar question earlier without realizing that that wasn't quite specific enough.

So I have this function that has to take in all the arguments of a print function, with the ... and all, and then put it into a queue that will call the actual print function later.

Something like:

```
std::queue<SOMETHING> queue;
template <typename... Params>
void printLater(int a, int b, char* fmt, Params ...args) {
    queue.push(args);
}

template <typename... Params>
void print(int a, int b, char* fmt, Param ...args) {
    //whatever
}

void actuallyPrint() {
    //whatever
    print(queue.pop());
}
```

Context: I'm working with a piece of hardware that can only handle requests every 50ms or else they're ignored. My goal is to create a wrapper that will automatically add the delays if I send it a bunch at once.

My fallback if I cant do this, although I'd rather do this is just sprintf (or C++ equivalent) into a string only store the string in the queue and call `print()` without all the args.

Comment: I am not sure why you posted a new question instead of improving your other one. I voted the other one as duplicate of this one, since it is not specific enough to really be answered but is clearly intended to be the same question as here.

Comment: In these cases what you should have done is edit your first question including the additional information. Notice there's a link bellow the question saying:"edit", try clicking that.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this perhaps:

```
std::queue<std::function<void()>> queue;

template <typename... Params>
void printLater(int a, int b, char* fmt, Params ...args) {
    queue.push([=](){ print(a, b, fmt, args...); } );
}

void actuallyPrint() {
    queue.front()();
    queue.pop();
}
```